# Getting private Flickr photos using flickr API using OAuth token

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, flickr

I have this URL that gives me only public photos -

```
https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&
api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&user_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=json
```

By authenticating the user I'm already getting Username, OAuth token and OAuth verifier.

How do I get all the private photos ?